# Xchat : How to hide join/leave messages

Tags: irc, xchat

I am wondering if there is a way to hide the 'blalbal has joins the #channel' messages for people joining and leaving. There are so many of them. I am using the IRC client Xchat.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

yes click at settings of that channel , there you will find the option as hide join/part Messages .

[image]

Comment: is this permanent?

Comment: yes it is .@user320

Comment: It wasn't permanent for me. Following [these steps](http://blog.gnu-designs.com/solved-permanently-setting-hide-joinpart-messages-off-in-xchat/), if you type `/set irc_conf_mode on` and then `/gui apply`, in the text field where you normally type messages and commands, and join/part messages will be disabled for all channels (I don't know how to do this selectively, though).

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron you should definitely post this as an answer as it is an even better solution, as it allows do it all by one command (well two, but still)

Answer (score 13):

Another alternative to hide join/part messages for **all** channels is to type a couple of commands (in the text field where you normally enter messages):

```
/set irc_conf_mode on
/gui apply
```

I don't know how to use it selectively on only some channels, though.

Comment: Is it usefull for mIRC client on Windows?