# How can I make Hexchat default all its channels to "Hide Join/Part Messages"?

Tags: irc, hexchat

How can I make Hexchat default all its channels to "Hide Join/Part Messages"?

I hate having to select it manually, and the settings do not seem to save when I close hexchat. Is there any way I can configure it so it defaults all channels I join to hide those messages?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xchat : How to hide join/leave messages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/356054/xchat-how-to-hide-join-leave-messages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My own testing on Hexchat under Trusty Tahr:

```
andrew@corinth:~$ hexchat --version
HexChat 2.9.6
```

could not reproduce this problem. I made the alteration in the preferences as doubtless you did as well:

[image]

and the setting was preserved after shutdown. I note that the Xchat FAQs speak of this setting:

```
/set irc_conf_mode 1
```

which activates 'Conference' mode where globally you will not be able to see the parts and joins. Perhaps try this although the *same setting* is used in the Hexchat preferences gui as illustrated above.

You could also temporarily remove the Hexchat config files:

```
mv -v $HOME/.config/hexchat/ $HOME/.config/hexchat_bak
```

and then restart Hexchat and see if *default* configs will enable the above alterations to work...

To return your old config files, if you should wish to do so, you would of course run:

```
mv -v $HOME/.config/hexchat_bak $HOME/.config/hexchat
```

**References:**

- [11. How do I turn on Conference mode where I will not see join or part messages?](http://xchat.org/faq/#q211)